# Stretching UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I have two view and a button one of the view is hidden "View1" and the other is not "View2" , and once I click on the button "View1" will appear , but I want "View2" to go down , I will add image show what I want to do

[image]

Comment: Vertical stack view seems to be the perfect component for you. I believe animations should also work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

**Brute way, if your views has fix sizes:**

1, create 3 variables for the position of the views

```
var view1Center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
var view2CenterBefore: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
var view2CenterAfter: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 400)
```

2, In ViewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear set view's alpha to 0 and the positions

```
view1.alpha = 0
view2.alpha = 0
view1.center = view1Center
view2.center = view2CenterBefore
```

3, When you press the button, you should animate the moves and show view1.

```
@IBAction func showView1(_ sender: Any) {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
           view2.center = view2CenterAfter
  })
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animatios: {
      view1.alpha = 1
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `UIStackView` class for this with ease. We can add both the views in a UIStackView instance with `vertical` axis. `view1` height should have Highest constraint priority (999) instead of required (1000). This way when view1 is hidden, it's height constraint won't have conflict.

You can take reference of following code snippet:

```
let stack = UIStackView()
// aligns subviews in top to bottom manner
stack.axis = .vertical

stack.addArrangedSubview(view1)
stack.addArrangedSubview(view2)
```

When `view1` is kept hidden, `view2` will automatically move up. StackView should not be given height constraint so that it will have inferred height of summation of its subviews.